# Getting wrong values from jquery .offset()

Tags: jquery, html, css, offset

I'm getting wrong values from jquery .offset(), I think it is because of CSS but cannot find the error.

This is the HTML element I'm trying to get the offset of:

```
<div id="sedes" class="seccion_in">
</div>
```

This is the CSS

```
.seccion_in { position:relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

And this is the jquery:

```
console.log($("#sedes").offset());
```

And this is the working link: http://ficm.hacemoscodigo.com/asiste/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the "wrong" value you are getting and what value do you think you should be getting?

Comment: Console says jQuery is not loaded...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### IDs MUST BE UNIQUE!

You have `#sedes` located in `<div id="nav">` as well as a `#sedes` in `<div id="content">`. My guess is you are getting the `.offset()` of the `#sedes` in your `nav`.  Remove/rename the ID that element and you should be good.

Make sure to use a classes instead.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

Review the [jQuery API for `offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

It should be returning `{top: 0, left: 0}` because of the positioning of the parent.